# Calculating the Grand total of Amount row in mysql table Array in PHP

Tags: codeigniter

I have been working on  a management system in PHP Codeigniter and have been storing invoice_entries in an array which stores in this way.

`[{"description":"panadol","amount":"200"},{"description":"quinine","amount":"200"}]`

in mysql database.

I want to find the sum of all the amounts in the array in my model or view directly but have no idea how to do it. this is my model code i have been using;

```
function calculate_grand_total_amount($invoice_number)
    {
        $total_amount           = 0;
        $invoice                = $this->db->get_where('invoice', array('invoice_number' => $invoice_number))->result_array();
        foreach ($invoice as $row)
        {
            $invoice_entries    = json_decode($row['invoice_entries']);
            foreach ($invoice_entries as $invoice_entry)
                $total_amount  += $invoice_entry->amount;

            //$vat_amount         = $total_amount * $row['vat_percentage'] / 100;
            $account_total        = array_sum($invoice_entry);
            //$account_total        = SUM('amount');
        }

        return $account_total;
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try this : add this line in your query, $this->db->select('*, SUM(amount) AS amount', FALSE);

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code, I think following code will work to calculate sum of amount for a particular invoice.

```
function calculate_grand_total_amount($invoice_number)
{
    $total_amount           = 0;
    $invoice                = $this->db->get_where('invoice', array('invoice_number' => $invoice_number))->result_array();
    foreach ($invoice as $row)
    {
        $invoice_entries    = json_decode($row['invoice_entries']);
        foreach ($invoice_entries as $invoice_entry)
            $total_amount  += $invoice_entry->amount;



    }

    return $total_amount;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM();

```
$this->db->select('sum(amount) as total');
$this->db->where( array('invoice_number' => $invoice_number));
$result = $this->db->get('invoice')->row_object();

$sum=$result->total;
```